# Regex split string into N matches based on Regex

Tags: regex

I have a need to split a string into N number of matches based on another Regex:

Input text:

```
Start Point 123
some random text
some random text
some random text

Start Point 234
some other random text

Start Point 345
some more random text
```

And the regex I want to split on is:

```
(Start Point \d+)
```

When I run this in Regex I want the following 3 matches:

**Match 1**

```
Start Point 123
some random text
some random text
some random text
```

**Match 2**

```
Start Point 234
some other random text
```

**Match 3**

```
Start Point 345
some more random text
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the op wanted to split a bunch of text (containing several lines) into blocks, using a regex to match the start of a block. Here's my proposed solution:

```
((?:__REGEX__)(?:.+|\n)+?(?=(?:__REGEX__)|\z))
```

- `__REGEX__` to be replaced with the expression that matches the start
  of a block.
- `(?:.+|\n)+?` will capture the rest of the block.
- `(?=(?:__REGEX__)|\z)` a look-ahead to make sure we're only
  capturing upto the next block or the end of buffer/string (`\z`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZnoJOI/1) where `__REGEX__` is `Start Point \d+`.

Also note that, the `(?:.+|\n)` can be replaced with just the wildcard `.` if the singleline flag is set, resulting in a simpler-looking expression: `((?:__REGEX__).+?(?=(?:__REGEX__)|\z))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
/^Start Point \d+(?:\n.+)*(?=\n\n|\z)/gm
```

in MULTILINE mode.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ICsEgO/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^Start Point \d+`: Match `Start Point` followed by a space and 1+ digits at the line start.
- `\n`: Match a line break
- `.+`: Match till end of line
- `(?:\n.+)*`: Match 0 or more of grouped expression
- `(?=\n\n|\z)`: Lookahead to assert that we have 2 newlines or end of input ahead

Comment: Thanks for this. How could take into account any number of characters between matches. As in could have a lot of text and line breaks etc.